# Pointing to Azure Event Hub instead of AWS Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-kinesis, azure-eventhub

My company currently uses Azure for our Data Warehousing infrastructure.  In the past we have used Azure Event Hubs for streaming data.  When working on previous projects this hasn't been an issue we just provide the connection details and they start sending us data.

However we have recently started working on a new project where most of their infrastructure is hosted on AWS, we have been asked to set up a Amazon Kinesis endpoint instead as they do not support Azure Event Hubs.

I don't know much about sending the data, but is it asking a lot to send to an Event Hub instead of Kinesis?

Comment: There's unfortunately no way to provide guidance for this, given that we don't have any control over the group that's providing Kinesis-only support. Maybe ask if they support Kafka? (Event Hubs has Kafka support)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for this is you could introduce a middle layer which understands both Kinesis and Event hub. And the middle layer I know is Spring Cloud Stream. It provides binder abstraction to supports various message middleware such as Kafka, Kinesis and Event hub.